# User location with geolocation API

Tags: geolocation

I want to get user location with geolocation API, it's getting location but no callback method is called.

```
        function success(postion) {
            console.log("Success Function");
            console.log(postion);
            alert(postion);
        }

        function error(message) {
            console.log("Error Function");
            console.log(message);
            alert(message);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            try
            {
                console.log("Getting location");
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
                console.log("Location Got Successfully");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        });
```

Here is the console log

```
Getting location  Test.aspx (line 53)
Location Got Successfully   Test.aspx (line 55)
```

Comment: Your browser should ask you if you want to allow the current site to access your location.

Comment: yeah, its asking me to allow access to location, even if i allowed it, i didn't do anything, surprisingly it works in Chrome & IE , but it fails in FF & Opera

Comment: It works just fine for me with Chrome and Firefox. Are you calling this script from a local HTML file, or are you running it from a hosted webpage?